# C++ Mock classes - How to solve this multiple-inheritance problem?

Tags: mocking, c++14, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I have drawn a class diagram to illustrate my question:

[Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJjmV.jpg)

Its a simple class hierarchy with some abstract interface classes. The grey classes show some mockups which I want to use for testing. As usual, the mockups derive from the interface classes. This is fine for 'MockAnimal' but confronts me with some problems at 'MockFish' and MockBird'.

To not copy code and to simplify my mockups, it would be great to use the mocked methods of 'MockAnimal' in these classes (multiple inheritance). Then I would just have to override/mock the methods from the sub-interfaces ('IFish' and 'IBird'). This wont work because im facing some kind of the diamond problem here i guess, because the methods of 'MockAnimal' are also implemented in 'ConcreteAnimal'. Thereofore my 'MockFish' and 'MockBird' will get those two implementations but I just want the ones from 'MockAnimal'.

As a workaround I changed my class hierarchy and just derived 'MockFish' and 'MockBird' from the interfaces 'IFish' and 'IBird'. But thats not a good solution in my opinion because the mockups will use the whole implementations of 'ConcreteAnimal'.

I hope that was understandable. Is there any good solution to achieve what I want?